# Uneven load and schema disagreements in 3 node Cassandra cluster

Tags: database, cassandra, distributed, bigdata, nosql

I have a 3 node single-datacenter Cassandra cluster consisting of nodes **A** (10.0.0.1), **B** (10.0.0.2) and **C** (10.0.0.3). Significative configurations include:

- GossipingPropertyFileSnitch (dc=dc1, rack=rack1)
- Seed node: **A** (see section: Steps taken)
- NetworkTopologyStrategy
- Replication factor: 3

#### The Problem:

Running *nodetool status* yields the following output:

```
    Datacenter: dc1
    ===============
    Status=Up/Down
    |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host         ID                               Rack
    UN  10.0.0.1  177.41 MiB  256          100.0%                    0a8da3f3-73d0-4d2f-bf97-e002d91a444f  rack1
    UN  10.0.0.2  144.34 MiB  256          100.0%                    5d8ca11f-a1c2-4381-aeeb-ed824ceafc96  rack1
    UN  10.0.0.3  44.36 MiB  256          100.0%                    b20a490e-b54d-4c65-800c-56d98f5a86dd  rack1
```

which indicates that the load balacing isn't working properly. Furthermore, *nodetool describecluster* indicates a schema disagreement.

```
    Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
            a4dade6e-d3a1-3168-8ea0-b7ffb11bc742: [10.0.0.1]

            f2dcee06-79c5-3855-9305-ce8ad2ee7fe4: [10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3]
```

#### Steps taken

- Port forwarding and checking connection on all nodes
- Different combinations of seed nodes (**A**, **B**, **C**, **A**/**B**, **B**/**C**, **A**/**B**/**C**, **A**/**C**)
- *nodetool repair* on all nodes (without errors)

#### Edit 1:

---

*nodetool resetlocalschema* on **A** (10.0.0.1) did not solve the schema disagreement, not even after running it on **B** (10.0.0.2) and **C** (10.0.0.3).

#### Edit 2:

---

The schema disagreement issue was resolved after gracefully shutting down all three nodes and repeating the process described in **Edit 1**.

```
    Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
            f2dcee06-79c5-3855-9305-ce8ad2ee7fe4: [10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3]
```

The load balancing issue still remains.

Comment: You only have one DC so as long as the nodes only have the same seed node(s) that part shouldn't be a problem. First try running `nodetool resetlocalschema` on node `10.0.0.1` and see if it moves into schema with `.2` and `.3`. If not then do the same on 2 and 3 until they are in sync. Then you can look at the data distribution after.

Comment: Hey and thanks for your reply. This did not solve it unfortunatetly, I updated the question.

Comment: Mismatched versions can cause schema disagreements, but I'm assuming all is ok here. The next step would be checking logs for warnings and errors that might lead to schema disagreement, can you share the logs somewhere?

Comment: I managed to resolve the schema disagreement issue (update the OP), not sure if it was a coincidence or not though.

Comment: Good work on getting that sorted. Now you have schema agreement I would probably run repair around the cluster, then check to see what your load data sizes look like then